# Code First with model coming from seperate database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm creating a chat system but the user table is from a seperate database. But on my database, I have `Message` which has a `User` parent. How do I handle a situation like this? I know when a user is logged in and I have their Id. Should I create a new user table and if the id does not exist I create it when creating a new message? What other option is there?

I'm using Entity Framework Code-first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `Message` table with just `UserId` column. Data integrity and loading of related user would be done by your application logic. EF doesn't need to know anything about that.